# Hibernate: transaction fails

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a @ManyToOne relationship. A client has many do_orders. I've already have the clients correctly saved in the database.

This is what I get when I initialize the program:

> Hibernate: select sequence_next_hi_value from hibernate_sequences where sequence_name = 'DO_ORDER' 
>   Hibernate: update hibernate_sequences set sequence_next_hi_value = ? where sequence_next_hi_value = ? and sequence_name = 'DO_ORDER' Hibernate: select sequence_next_hi_value from hibernate_sequences where sequence_name = 'ITEM' 
>   Hibernate:update hibernate_sequences set sequence_next_hi_value = ? where sequence_next_hi_value = ? and sequence_name = 'ITEM'

But, when I try to save the orders, I get the following exception:

```
control.database.DatabaseAccessFailException: Transaction Fail
at control.database.DAO.commitTransaction(DAO.java:35)
at control.servlets.ConfirmOrder.doPost(ConfirmOrder.java:74)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.securityfilter.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Here are three classes of the project which might be involved:

Client

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class Client extends User implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "wishes", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "genericItem_id")})
    private List<GenericItem> wishlist;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Item.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "inbag", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "item_id")})
    private List<Item> shoppingbag;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client")
    private List<Do_Order> doOrders;

    public Client() {
        super();
        this.wishlist = new ArrayList<GenericItem>() ;
        this.shoppingbag = new ArrayList<Item>();
        this.doOrders = new ArrayList<Do_Order>();
    }

    public Client(String name, String email, String password, Integer document) {
        super(name, email, password, document, UserType.CLIENT);
        this.wishlist = new ArrayList<GenericItem>() ;
        this.shoppingbag = new ArrayList<Item>();
        this.doOrders = new ArrayList<Do_Order>();
    }

    public Client(String name, String email, String password, Integer document, List<GenericItem> wishlist,
                  List<Item> shoppingbag) {
        super(name, email, password, document, UserType.CLIENT);
        this.wishlist = wishlist;
        this.shoppingbag = shoppingbag;
        this.doOrders = new ArrayList<Do_Order>();
    }

    public List<GenericItem> getWishlist() {
        return wishlist;
    }

    public void setWishlist(List<GenericItem> wishlist) {
        this.wishlist = wishlist;
    }

    public void addToWishlist(GenericItem genericItem) {
        wishlist.add(genericItem);
    }

    public void removeFromWishlist(GenericItem genericItem) {
        wishlist.remove(genericItem);
    }

    public List<Item> getShoppingbag() {
        return shoppingbag;
    }

    public void setShoppingbag(List<Item> shoppingbag) {
        this.shoppingbag = shoppingbag;
    }

    public void addToShoppingbag(Item item) {
        shoppingbag.add(item);
    }

    public void removeFromShoppingbag (Item item) {
        shoppingbag.remove(item);
    }

    public List<Do_Order> getDoOrders() {
        return doOrders;
    }

    public void setDoOrders(List<Do_Order> doOrders) {
        this.doOrders = doOrders;
    }

    public void addOrder(Do_Order order) {
        doOrders.add(order);
    }
}
```

Do_Order

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DO_ORDER")
public class Do_Order implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private long order_id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "INORDER", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")})
    private List<Item> items;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
    private Brand brand;
    @Column(name = "delivered")
    private boolean delivered;
    @Column(name = "current_date")
    private Date current_date;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Client client;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;
    @Column(name = "order_price")
    private float order_price;


    public Do_Order() {

    }

    public Do_Order(Client client, Address address, Brand brand) {
        this.client = client;
        this.address = address;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        current_date = new Date();
        delivered = false;
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
        order_price += item.getGenericItem().getGenericItem_price();
    }



    public long getOrder_id() {
        return order_id;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public boolean isDelivered() {
        return delivered;
    }

    public void confirmDelivery() {
        delivered = true;
    }

    public Date getCurrent_date() {
        return current_date;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public float getOrder_price() {
        return order_price;
    }

    public Brand getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }
}
```

Item:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
public class Item implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private long item_id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "genericItem_id")
    private GenericItem genericItem;
    private Size size;

    public Item() {

    }

    public Item(GenericItem genericItem, Size size) {
        this.genericItem = genericItem;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public long getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public GenericItem getGenericItem() {
        return genericItem;
    }

    public Size getSize() {
        return size;
    }

}
```

Now the servlet's method:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    DatabaseManager databaseManager = (DatabaseManager) httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("databaseManager");

    List<Item> shoppingbag= (List<Item>) httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("shoppingbag");

    Client client = (Client) httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("client");

    Address address = (Address) httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("address");

    List<Do_Order> associatedOrders = (List<Do_Order>) httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute(associatedOrders);

    OrderDAO orderDAO = databaseManager.getOrderDAO();
    orderDAO.beginTransaction();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < associatedOrders.size(); i++) {
        orderDAO.save(associatedOrders.get(i));
    }

    try {
        orderDAO.commitTransaction();
    } catch (DatabaseAccessFailException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? That exception is probably wrapping another exception with more information about the root cause of the problem.

Comment: How large is your associatedOrders List? You should normally attempt to flush and clear the Session periodically to manage your first-level cache. Doing the way you have it implemented may cause a number of issues with resource consumption if your list is large. As fipple stated, there may be more to the exception chain than what is posted.